# Add and display all values

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 2 tables called Item & Items_in_issue_Note(Items_in_issue_Note is a many to many table).

In Item table there is a column called Available_Qty and in Items_in_issue_Note there is a column called Issued_Qty.

I want to get the sum of Issued_Qty for each item and add it to Available_Qty in each item and display them item wise to get the Quantity before issue items.

I know how to get the sum of Issued_Qty by using

```
select ItemCode, sum(Issued_Qty) 
from Items_In_Issue_Note 
group by ItemCode
```

and how to get the Available_Qty by using

```
select itemCode,Available_Qty 
from Item
```

and know how to get the quantity per item by using

```
select 
    itemCode,
    Available_Qty + (select sum(Issued_Qty)
                     from Items_In_Issue_Note 
                     where ItemCode='I001') 
from Item 
where ItemCode='I001'
```

But want to know how to get the output for all the items.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using group by and join you may get the desired result. Try the following

```
select 
  A.itemCode,
  A.Available_Qty + Coalesce(sum(B.Issued_Qty),0) 
from Item A left join 
Items_In_Issue_Note B on A.ItemCode=B.ItemCode
group by A.itemCode,A.Available_Qty
```

Your code modified below one is modified based on sub-query depends on main table value

```
select 
itemCode,
Available_Qty + (select sum(Issued_Qty)
                 from Items_In_Issue_Note 
                 where ItemCode=Item.ItemCode) 
from Item
```

Best way is follow join instead of sub-query because sub-query gives performance issue.

Comment: Thank you! this is working perfectly. May I know Why we use 'A' and 'B' (eg- A.itemCode, B.Issued_Qty) and Coalesce(sum(B.Issued_Qty),0). I just want to know the concept.

Comment: Sub-queries do not in themselves have performance issues. They are a perfectly valid option in many cases.

Comment: @Tharindu giving alias name for table it reduce the length of query instead we can use Table Name. **Learn Join's** you will get final conclusion. Those are easy to understand. gives more effective result's if design **tables with primary key and foreign key relation**

Comment: @UpenderReddy I will read it. by the way Thank you for the support!

Comment: @Tharindu increase my Reputation may boost my energy ;-)